# Get array position and send it through an Intent

Tags: java, android, android-activity

I am trying to send data from an array of objects to a new activity.
I'm using a List view with a  `list.setOnItemClickListener`
What I want to do, is to send the array data to a new Activity that is created when you click an item in the listview.

```
@Override
public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {

    try {
        HashMap<String, Object> casos = new HashMap<String, Object>((HashMap<String, Object>) snapshot.getValue());
        for (Object caso : casos.values()) {
            HashMap<String, Object> casoMap = (HashMap<String, Object>) caso;
            DatosCaso nuevosdatos = new DatosCaso((String)casoMap.get("nombre"), (String)casoMap.get("sexo"),(String) casoMap.get("edad"), (String)casoMap.get("color"),(String) casoMap.get("tamanio"), (String)casoMap.get("raza"), (String)casoMap.get("descripcion"), (String)casoMap.get("ubicacion"),(String)casoMap.get("contacto"),(String)casoMap.get("imagen"), (String)casoMap.get("fecha"));
            datos.add(nuevosdatos);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.d("NUEVOCASO", e + "");
    }
    // thread executing here can get info from database and make subsequent call
    Collections.addAll(datos);
    ponerCasoEnListview(datos); //this puts the array into a listView

}
```

this is how I populate the data in my array.

Then I used this but I dont know how to send the array.

```
list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                int position, long id) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Intent intent = new Intent(CasosPerdidosActivity.this, CasoActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);

        }
    });
```

Should I putExtra(Arraylist) or something like that?

Comment: do you want to send a `List<Datos>` to `CasoActivity`?

Comment: An ArrayList<Datos>. But yes.

Comment: does `Datos` implement `Parcelable`?

Comment: no, should I add Parcelable?

Comment: you should definitely make `Datos` implement it

Answer (score 0):

For sending data objects through `Intent`, use `Bundle` and try using `Gson` library. Pack those objects into JSONString via Gson, and unpack it in new  Activity ( in your case `CasoActivity`).

To get more familiar with Gson library, go to https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide

Answer (score 0):

`putParcelableArrayListExtra()` or Transform List to `JSONString`.